# Mongoose / find document and extract object from array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There is many question on that subject, but everything i could find and tried did not worked on my cases
I have the following mongodb schema

```
var descSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: "String"
    },
    base_name: {
        type: "String"
    },
    type: {
        type: "String"
    },
    size: {
        type: "String"
    }
});

var BaseSchema = new Schema({
    base_name: {
        type: "String",
        unique: true
    },
    friendly_name: {
        type: "String"
    },
    type: {
        type: "String"
    },
    sizes: [
        {
            name: "String",
            value: "String",
            naming: descSchema
        }
    ],
    description: {
        type: "String"
    }
});
```

I need to find a document that match the `base_name` (that works fine with `db.find({base_name: myvariable}, function(err, element){...});`), but from that search I need to extract only the object `naming` stored in the `sizes` object array that match `"name" = "myvalue"` of the previous searched document...

I did it with and map/indexOf but is not very elegant, and I am sure that there is a faster way to performed it

```
db.findOne({
    base_name: "myname"
}, "sizes", function (err, element) {
    var tmp = element.toObject();
    var index = tmp.sizes.map(function (a) {
        return a.name;
    }).indexOf("myvalue");
    console.log(tmp.sizes[index].naming);

});
```

below a sample of the collection:

```
[
    { 
        _id: 5b76e89b7275781a484e3b14,
        base_name: 'name1',
        friendly_name: 'my geate name',
        image_folder: 'img',
        instruction_folder: 'notice',
        fournitures_folder: 'fournitures',
        type: 'standard',
        cover: 'cover.jpg',
        owner: 'owner.jpg',
        sizes:
        [
            {
                name: 'size01',
                value: '48',
                naming: {
                    name: 'Prototype_01',
                    base_name: 'Prototype_01',
                    friendly_name: 'Prototype PAC 01',
                    type: 'standard',
                    size: '48',
                    nb_item: 3,
                    items: [
                        ...
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'size02',
                value: '47',
                naming: {
                    name: 'Prototype_02',
                    base_name: 'Prototype_02',
                    friendly_name: 'Prototype PAC 02',
                    type: 'standard',
                    size: '47',
                    nb_item: 3,
                    items: [
                        ...
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                ...
            }
        ],
        popularity: 5,
        woo_id: '51'
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

And what I would like to retrieve if i requested the size 47

```
{
    name: 'Prototype_02',
    base_name: 'Prototype_02',
    friendly_name: 'Prototype PAC 02',
    type: 'standard',
    size: '47',
    nb_item: 3,
    items: [
        ...
    ]
}
```